# Multiple small deletes

Tags: oracle, index, delete

I have a script that loops over records of people (~4 million) and executes multiple updates (~100) and a single delete statement (all of these updates and delete are on different tables).  The problem I am facing is that the one delete statement takes about half the run time by itself.  I understand that when you execute a delete statement, it needs to update the index, but I find it rather ridiculous. I am currently testing this script with one thread using `dbms_parallel_execute` but I plan to multithread this script.

I am executing a query similar to the following:

```
DELETE FROM table1 t1
WHERE (t1.key1, t1.key2) IN (SELECT t2.key1, t2.key2
                               FROM table2 t2
                              WHERE t2.parm1 = 1234
                                AND t2.parm2 = 5678).
```

Following facts:

- Table2 (~30 million records) is ~10 times larger than table1 (~3 million records).
- There is a primary key on table1(key1, key2)
- There is a primary key on table2(key1, key2)
- There is an index on table2(parm1, parm2)
- I have disabled the foreign key constraint on table1(key1, key2) that references table2(key1, key2)
- There are no other constraints on table1, but many more constraints on table2.
- All triggers on table1 have been disabled
- The explain plan for this query comes up with a cost lower than that of many of my update statements (but I know this doesn't account for much).

Explain plan output:

```
DELETE STATEMENT                    6
DELETE                              
NESTED LOOPS                        6
NESTED LOOPS                        6
TABLE ACCESS        BY INDEX ROWID  4
INDEX               RANGE SCAN      3
INDEX               UNIQUE SCAN     1
TABLE ACCESS        BY INDEX ROWID  2
```

I was wondering if there were any way to make this delete go faster.  I tried to do a `bulk delete` but it didn't seem to improve the run time.  If there were any way to execute all the deletes and then update the index after, I suspect it would run faster.  Obviously doing a create table from a select is out of the picture since I am looping over records (and running through multiple conditions) from another table to do the delete.

Answer (score 1):

I'd consider:

1. If the table is partitioned - to disable the index partitions on the specific partitions which are going to be changed, and rebuild (`rebuild online` probably) them after the operation.
2. Increase the amount of memory in disposal (for the specific session), so that it won't do any I/O operations (on temporary tablespace) at all, by changing `workarea_size_policy` to `'manual'` and  `sort_area_size`, `hash_area_size` to the maximum size you can spare for this operation.
3. Run the entire operation using `parallel` hint (or `parallel_index` if you'd decide to use some indexes after all).
4. Switch all the accessed objects to `nologging` mode, so that redo logs won't be generated during the operation (and switch back to `logging` right after it's finished of course).